# Revision not working for content type using workbench moderation module

Tags: users, nodes, workbench

We have 7-8 content type. We are using workbench moderation module for revision and create draft.
This module works fine with all content type except one content type.
All settings are same for all content type.

When I edit content and save as draft, it gets published and anonymous user can see updated content. It should not visible to anonymous user as updated content saved as draft.

Anyone one have idea, what is the problem.